# Flutter web hosted in Firebase role based "admin page" and "user page"

Tags: flutter, firebase, role-based-access-control

My proposal is redirect if the user has an "admin role" or "user role".

Then the code of the login_page is

```
void _logIn() async {
    try {
      final newUser = await Auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword_xp(
        email: _controllerEmail.text,
        password: _controllerPassword.text,
      );
      if (newUser != null) {
        final docSnapshot =
            await Auth().getUserIfno(newUserMail: newUser.email.toString());
        if (docSnapshot.exists) {
          role = docSnapshot.data()!['role'];
          if (role == "admin1") {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(admin_page.route);
          } else {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(user_page.route);
          }
        }
      } 
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

It works as expected. But if anyone writes it in the browser, anyone can access "**localhost:55352/#/admin_page**"

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntLVA.jpg)

Then, I tried to secure the admin_page if not "admin role" redirecting to user_page by this way:

```
class admin_page extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String route = '/admin_page';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (role != "admin1") {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(user_page.route);
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'admin_page',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('admin_page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The idea worked and the admin_page is redirected, but the Flutter project stops and thows this erros:

> ═╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following assertion was thrown building admin_page$(dirty):
> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
> This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
> process of building widgets.

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaQGS.jpg)

Is there any better practice or suggestion to secure single web-pages in Flutter web?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here:

["setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build" error trying to push a replacement in Navigator inside a Consumer widget (provider package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58030360/setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build-error-trying-to-push-a-repl)

Finally the code in the admin_page is:

```
class admin_page extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String route = '/admin_page';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (role != "admin1") {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/");
      }
    });

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('admin_page'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            "admin_page",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        );
  }
}
```

Problem solved. It now redirects as expected without advising error missage.